# issue in rebasing and squashing in GIT

Tags: git, rebase

I am facing a issue while rebasing my branch with LIVE.
I have created one branch sa_hotfix with master and made one commit and accidentally i merged it in master. once i know, i reverted the commit on master using below command:
**git revert x**
now commit on sa_hotfix branch is:

```
 x  (my commit)  
 a  
 b
```

and my master branch commit are (after  adding some more merge):

```
xyz  
tvd  
**ret**  (revert of my accidental merge)  
**x**   (my commit)  
a  
b
```

now I am going to rebase my branch with master using below method

```
git checkout master
git checkout sa_hotfix
git rebase -i origin/master
```

but after rebasing my branch's commit are looks like the same as master branch. I also got a "**noop**" message in squashing edit window.

is it possible to rebase my branch without checking the master branch's commit `x` and commit `rev`?

Comment: Can you please edit the post and be clear on the sequence. I need to know if and when you pushed out the code. How did you revert the code onmaster ? Are you talking about reverting the code locally ? What command did you use to rebase your branch against master ?

Comment: post updated. after reverting the master locally, i also pushed the master to origin..

Comment: from your sa_hotfix branch perform the following , git pull --rebase origin/master   and then git rebase -i head~5 .

Comment: why are you using **head~5 **? I have just given the example it may be that there are 10 commits in master

Comment: Okay u could use ~10 as well. So you haven't pushed out the changes on master ?oh ok ignore that question i dint see your update.ok. So even after a git pull --rebase origin/master sa_hotfix does not show the latest changes in master ? Is that the issue ?

Comment: i got error while running the command git pull --rebase origin/master
fatal: 'origin/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Sorry i typed a / inside. It will be git pull --rebase origin master .

Comment: So even after a git pull --rebase origin/master sa_hotfix does not show the latest changes in master ? yes this is the issue and after doing your command..branch is like a master one as i have mentioned

Comment: Hmm did you try git rebase -i head~10 while on the sa_hotfix branch ?

Comment: git rebase -i head~10
fatal: Needed a single revision
Invalid base

Comment: try git rebase -i --root

Comment: git rebase -i --root  
You must specify --onto when using --root

Comment: why do you think that is necessary ? Also do you know how many commits are there in your branch ?